# ASP.NET prevent jquery-ocupload plugin make form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Old ASP.NET Classic site(NETFramework 4) was working fine with this jQuery Plugin - https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/jquery-ocupload/blob/master/jquery.ocupload.js - page with this uploader worked outside ASP.NET.

But I rebuild this site and PopUp Windows with uploader I have placed inside ASP.NET form tag and place it on ASP.NET page.

After that this Uploader stop working. This Uploader has Submit function.

```
        submit: function () {
            if (this.onSubmit()) {

                $('input[type=hidden]', form).remove();

                $.each(options.params, function (key, value) {
                    form.append($(
                    '<input ' +
                        'type="hidden" ' +
                        'name="' + key + '" ' +
                        'value="' + value + '" ' +
                    '/>'
                ));
                });

                $('input[name=uploadtime]', form).val(getNTime());
                form.submit();
```

How to correct modify this submit function (where is correct place to add e.preventDefault()) and maybe need something modifying (additionally to  EnableEventValidation="false") in ASP.NET?

On the screen below there is a wrong place, submit still don't working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have understand what happens. Button "Обрати файл" (Select file) is dummy stub, this is not a real button

And real upload button follow mouse. If width of dummy button is wrong click never happens to real upload button.

Screen below demonstrate this scene. I increase <form height and width and add red border to form to better understanding.

[image]